# How to handle changed remote tag with go modules

Tags: git, go

I am currently working on a first release for some tool I wrote in Go. The tool has two components that are individually versioned (one being a plugin API).

During development, I had a hard time getting to know how to handle those modules and finally set up two separate repositories. I created some tags for the plugin API which I pushed to remote, one of which was `v0.1.0`. This was a dumb idea as it wasn't really `v0.1.0` and I just wanted to have some tag to refer to.

Anyway, now I'm trying to draft a release. Therefore, I deleted the `v0.1.0` tag locally and in the remote repository, created a new one (which refers to another commit) and pushed it to the remote repo.

The problem is that I can't make Go forget the old `v0.1.0`. I tried the following things:

```
go clean -i url/to/api
rm -rf ~/go/pkg/mod/url/to/api@v0.1.0
go clean --modcache
```

But no matter what I do, whenever I execute

```
go get -u url/to/api@v0.1.0
```

it downloads the old version. I check this by inspecting the code in `~/go/pkg/mod/url/to/api@v0.1.0`.

I tried it on another machine which didn't have the module installed before, and to my horror, it also downloaded the old version *even though there are no traces of the old tag in the repo*.

What is going on here? Does Go have some kind of central memory of module versions? How can I make it forget the old version and download the new one?

**Edit:**

To be extra sure, I tried

```
git clone -b v0.1.0 https://url/to/api.git
```

And that checks out the api at the correct version. So `go` must be doing… something else.

Comment: Have not tried this, but `go clean -cache -modcache` might rip out the entire cache and all its data. Or it might not. Your best bet is never to move a tag anyway: Git itself has the same problem, i.e., someone might have copied your repository *and its tags* and assume that the tags never move, because they're never supposed to move.

Comment: I think `go clean -cache -modcache` *won't* work, given what you found on a second machine. It looks like you have a tag-to-hash-ID cache somewhere further up the chain, not on your local machines at all. That's the one you'd have to update.

Comment: So, if you just consider the tag `v0.1.0` to be forever poisoned, and stop using it entirely, that will sidestep the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem of the proxy.golang. It caches the tags and the code to improve the performance of handling a large number of requests. I have the same problem at the moment. It seems like I have to wait some time until the cache of the proxy updates or just use a new tag.

---

Cached tags can be found here: [https://proxy.golang.org/{PROJECTNAME}/@v/list](https://proxy.golang.org/%7BPROJECTNAME%7D/@v/list)

Replace {PROJECTNAME} and {TAG}

---

Cached code can be downloaded here: [https://proxy.golang.org/{PROJECTNAME}/@v/{TAG}.zip](https://proxy.golang.org/%7BPROJECTNAME%7D/@v/%7BTAG%7D.zip)

Replace {PROJECTNAME} and {TAG}

---

Have a look into the FAQ

---

FAQ from https://proxy.golang.org/ :

### I committed a new change (or released a new version) to a repository, why isn't it showing up when I run go get -u or go list -m --versions?

In order to improve our services' caching and serving latencies, new versions may not show up right away. If you want new code to be immediately available in the mirror, then first make sure there is a semantically versioned tag for this revision in the underlying source repository. Then explicitly request that version via go get module@version. The new version should be available within one minute. Note that if someone requested the version before the tag was pushed, it may take up to 30 minutes for the mirror's cache to expire and fresh data about the version to become available. If the version is still not available after 30 minutes, please file an issue.

### I removed a bad release from my repository but it still appears in the mirror, what should I do?

Whenever possible, the mirror aims to cache content in order to avoid breaking builds for people that depend on your package, so this bad release may still be available in the mirror even if it is not available at the origin. The same situation applies if you delete your entire repository. We suggest creating a new version and encouraging people to use that one instead.

Comment: I don't have the setup to test this anymore, but I'll accept this because it seems to make sense.